# Why does total energy of N coupled harmonic oscillators increase with increase in N?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I am trying to analyse the energy behaviour of n coupled harmonic oscillators where the initial displacements are distributed/defined by sine wave equation at various values of time. My total energy plot seems to appx. double from n= 4 to 8 to 16 and so on. Can someone please explain me the behaviour. thanks.[image]

Comment: Is this data from a simulation? Then the answer is "because the programmer is giving the same amount of energy to each oscillator rather than dividing it among them." No physics at all, just a decision by a coder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total energy is determined by your initial conditions, i.e., initial position and velocity of each oscillator. So when you double to number of oscillators while keeping the distribution of initial conditions approximately constant, you're setting your system in a state of approximately twice the energy.

Comment: thank you!. But when my initial condition is with first particle displacement as 1 and the rest at zero, with two coupled oscillators I get a total energy of 0.5 and for all others it stays at 1. Why is that?

Comment: @wannabegeek, with "for all others" you mean for other number of coupled oscillators (3, 4,...)? If so, I'd say there's something wrong in the case of two oscillators, because it should also have total energy equal to the sum of initial energies, which is also $1$.